pipreqs django UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 81: invalid start byte
trying to make a requirements.txt file but get an error
what do i do?
   (.venv) root@vm-89f2b1ea:~/code/aigenback# pipreqs ~/code/aigenback
    INFO: Not scanning for jupyter notebooks.
    <unknown>:165: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
    <unknown>:166: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
    <unknown>:207: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
    <unknown>:456: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/bin/pipreqs", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
                 ^^^^^^
      File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 609, in main
        init(args)
      File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 533, in init
        candidates = get_all_imports(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 136, in get_all_imports
        contents = read_file_content(file_name, encoding)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 181, in read_file_content
        contents = f.read()
                   ^^^^^^^^
      File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 81: invalid start byte

also i've tried:
(.venv) root@vm-89f2b1ea:~/code/aigenback# pipreqs --encoding utf-8
INFO: Not scanning for jupyter notebooks.
<unknown>:165: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
<unknown>:166: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
<unknown>:207: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
<unknown>:456: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/bin/pipreqs", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 609, in main
    init(args)
  File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 533, in init
    candidates = get_all_imports(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 136, in get_all_imports
    contents = read_file_content(file_name, encoding)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/code/aigenback/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pipreqs/pipreqs.py", line 181, in read_file_content
    contents = f.read()
               ^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 81: invalid start byte


pipreqs . --ignore ".venv"

something was wrong with encoding in my .venv packages so we ignore them completely
more details here: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/214
